# Cassandra nodetool status showing "?N" on nodes

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

After come time using cassandra on a 4 nodes cluster, it started to return "connection refused error" when i try to run cqlsh and my nodetool status is showing a "?N" state on the nodes except the node i'm in.

[image: nodetool status]

how can i fix it?

Comment: please check once system.log and debug.log, you may get some clue..

Comment: it means cassandra does not knwo whether these nodes ar UP or DOWN ..it may be due to corrupt gossip..check logs and also check peers table (all correct peer entries  should be present.)

Answer (score 0):

Stop Cassandra service in all nodes. Then start all seed nodes first and then start all non seed nodes.